# Raw socket send and receive

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, udp

Just for the purpose of learning raw sockets in C I am writing a simple server that uses raw sockets to receive and send messages.

I create the socket

```
if ((r_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP))< 0){
   perror("socket");
   exit(-1);
}
```

Then I create an infinite loop and start receiving, processing, and replying

```
while(1){
   if((n = recvfrom(r_sock, buffer, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &client_len))<0){
      perror("recvfrom");
      exit(-1);
   } 

   // Discard messages not intended to the server
   if(htons(udp->uh_dport) != my_port){
      continue;
   }

   //Do whatever with the data received and then send reply to client
   // ....

   if((n = sendto(r_sock, udp, ntohs(udp->uh_len), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client, client_len))<0){
      perror("sendto");
      exit(-1);
   } 
}
```

I am not showing here the definition of every single variable but for the sake of completeness, buffer is a char array of size BUFLEN (big enough) and udp is a struct udphdr pointer to the right position in the buffer.

The point is that I have another program that serves as client using standard UDP sockets (SOCK_DGRAM) which is proved to be working properly (I also tried with netcat just in case). When I send a message with the client, it never receives the reply back. It seems that when the server sends the reply to the client, the server itself gets the message and the client gets nothing.

So, my question is: is there a way of solving this with raw sockets? That is, to make the server not receive its own messages and preventing others from receiving them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have just realised that it was a problem with the checksum... Once I had a correct checksum in UDP the packet was correctly received by the client.

Wireshark gave me the lead to the solution. I saw that the checksum was not validated so I went to Edit > Preferences > Protocols > UDP > Validate the UDP checksum if possible and checked it.

Hope it helps